# CSS ::selection inline

Tags: html, css, textselection, inline-styles

I have a div, and I want to change the selection style.

It works fine like this:

```
<div>Text text</div>
<style>
div::selection {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
</style>
```

The problem is that I want to send it in the email, so it has to be `inline` code.

(`<div style=""></div>`)

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: But you can add the same as an internal style that you have done above. So is that not working?

Comment: @NathanLee Can you show me how to do that with `inline-style`?

Comment: Your way is correct, you just need to add the `<style>` under `<head>` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Inline styles pertain to elements, not pseudo-elements, so you cannot do this with an inline style.

I'm not entirely sure which non-webmail clients support `::selection` (other than Thunderbird with `::-moz-selection`) anyway. But  you should be able to get away with using an internal stylesheet, as you already are doing (except move the `<style>` element to `<head>` instead), depending on which clients you're supporting.

Personally I wouldn't bother with `::selection` in an email at all. There's virtually no need for it, especially when you consider the poor CSS support that email clients are often known for.

Comment: I agree with not including ::Selection Most likely, only outlook and maybe a few others will support it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is as follows. Inside the "head" tag of your email, simply include your style

```
<head>
<style>
div::selection {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    //your email body
```

I should also note here that Pseudo elements, such as div::selection, are selectors, and cannot be styled inline.